# Extract Date from Filename PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a few hundred thousand files from a few different sources. Each one of the files has the date in the name, however, the filename structure differs for example:

```
2015-10-05-importsrc1.txt
20151004importsrc2.txt
importsrc3-154826-4521-2015-10-06.csv
importsrc4-154826-4521-20151006.txt
```

I need to deal with files that are of the current month and the next month ignoring any older files.

I have seen a few examples of how to check specific files using loops to check the date required however I am trying to avoid too many loops and potentially using regex to pattern match a date and then do a comparison.

Currently I use the following (where `$f` is the file name and extension):

```
//CHANGED THIS TO SKIP OLD ONES
if(strpos(str_replace("-", "", $f), "201510") == false)
{
    continue;
}
```

But this only works for the previous month and is currently hard coded, ideally I need something like:

```
//CHANGED THIS TO SKIP OLD ONES
$extractedDate = preg_match('DATEPATTERN',(str_replace("-", "", $f), "201510"),$extractedDate );
if(strtotime($extractedDate[0]) < date('Y-m-d',(strtotime ('-1 Month', strtotime (date('Y-m-d)))))
{
    continue;
}
```

I know I could simply alter my first attempt, add another condition and make it dynamic but if I were able to extract the date this would help in so many ways.

Comment: Are you trying to say you are looking to match `201510` and `2015-11` like substrings in filenames? Something like [`2015[ -]?1[10]`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ8oF4/2)?

Comment: You should give other test cases (and some of wish you don't watn to keep), are the month and day always on two digits ?

Comment: @stribizhev why a space ?

Comment: @Tensibai: Because it is *something like*. The question is unclear, and that is how I am trying to pull out more details from OP.

Comment: @stribizhev oh ok. Didn't get it

Comment: The dates are always in the format 'Y-m-d' or 'Ymd', although other numbers can appear in the filename ie sequence number etc. @stribizhev Yes I would like to match say 201511 or 201510, but ideally I would like to extract the date so i can use this for other operations, so being able to extract it would be the best solution for me.

Comment: The [sample](https://ideone.com/Ddb8I8) shows how to get the dates you need. Change `$re` to `$re = '/\b2015-?\d{2}-?\d{2}\b/'; ` to extract all dates from Year 2015.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been unsuccessful finding anything on the web on how to do this. It seems there is no exact science. Using the comments above I have the following regex which works to match the files specified:

```
$re = '/(\d{8})|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/';
$str = "20151001-importsrc1.txt";
$str = "2015-10-01-importsrc1.txt";
$str = "01-10-2015-importsrc1.txt";
$str = "importsrc1-2015-10-01.txt";
$str = "importsrc1-01102015.txt";
$str = "importsrc1-01-10-2015.txt";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$date = str_replace("-", "", $matches[0]);
print_r($date);
```

There are three patterns to match `20151001`, `01102015`, `2015-10-01`, `01-10-2015`. From here I will be able to do a comparison of the date.

This is certainly not a definitive answer, but may help someone in future.